# Ruby on Rails 2.3.8: Functional Testing: assert_redirect_to not finding action?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, routes, functional-testing

Here is zhe error:

```
NoMethodError: undefined method `dashboard_url' for #<AccountsController:0x105212680 @real_format=nil>
```

and here is the function which generates the error (on the assert_redirected_to :dashboard line

```
def login_as_owner(login = SharedTest.user.login, password = SharedTest.user.password)
  old_controller = @controller
  @controller = SessionsController.new
  post(:create, :login => login, :password => password)
  @controller = AccountsController.new 
  assert_redirected_to :dashboard
  @controller = old_controller

end
```

I do controller switiching, because I need to be able to call this method from any of the functional tests, as the entire app requires being logged in first... though I'm not sure if I'm doing it right.

I ran rake routes, and here are the related routes

```
               root        /                              {:controller=>"accounts", :action=>"dashboard"}
  dashboard_account GET    /account/dashboard(.:format)   {:controller=>"accounts", :action=>"dashboard"}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try

```
assert_redirected_to :dashboard_account
```

or explicitly specifying url

```
assert_redirected_to '/account/dashboard'
```

Comment: btw just to clarify - "dashboard_account GET" that  you see in `rake routes` is actually prefix of 2 methods you can use to generate path/url: dashboard_account_path/dashboard_account_url